# Monaca＋OnsenUIアプリのios9でのタップ反応が悪化（セレクトピッカーが出ない）

Tags: javascript, monaca, onsen-ui

セレクトピッカーが反応する部分のコードは以下になります。

```
<div class="mod_form">
<form>
<div class="mod_form_select">
  <select class="Select2" name="sample1" select id="select_test" onchange="getS(this,'Question2');">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
```

ios8ではタップしてセレクトピッカーが出ないようなことはなかったです（自分のデバイスだけかもしれませんが）。

具体的に言いますと、何回かタップしているとそのうちセレクトピッカーが出てきて普通にセレクトできるようになる時があります。何回やっても出てこないときは何の反応もありません。ただ反応がおかしいセレクト（出たり消えたりが繰り返されます。それもすごいスピードです）がたまに現れたりします。そういった現象もios8ではありませんでした。

コーディングのし直しをしないといけないのでしょうか？ちなみにonsenUIを最新にアップデートしても直りませんでした。

vppを通して配布しているアプリですが今のところ「反応しない」との声は聞かれません。

ただそのうちios9が普及してくれば必ずこの問題は出てくると思われます。
どなたか同じ問題に直面している人、または問題を克服する方法をお知りのかた、ぜひ御教示いただけたらと思います。